# Calculate the area of the region bounded by $z=0, z=1,$, and $(z+1)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate the volume of the region bounded by $z=0, z=1,$, and $(z+1)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$

The integral is $\int_{B}z\text{ dV}$

The area is like the thing between the top two green places. The first place is $z=1$, second is $z=0$

Clearly we have $0\leq z\leq 1$, but I'm not sure what to bound next? Should I be using cylindrical?

Would it be correct in saying $0\leq r\leq \dfrac{1}{z+1}$
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're well on your way.  In cylindrical coordinates,
$$
    B = \left\{(r,\theta,z): 0 \leq z \leq 1,\ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi,\ 0 \leq r \leq \frac{1}{z+1}\right\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I would do this.

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1}\int_0^{\frac 1{z+1}} r \ dr\ dz\ d\theta$